# Top menu expands to the right unexpectedly

Tags: css

I have the following problem:

When scrolling down on my website, the top menu header expands unexpectedly to the right. The problem exists in FireFox and Chrome.

Visit my website to see what I mean: www.robvanderstaaij.nl

Thanks for any help.

Regards,

Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your stylesheet, change `max-width: 1260px;` with `max-width: 1060px;`

in style.css, line #835

```
.site-header {
    background-color: #000;
    max-width: 1260px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 4;
}
```

with

```
.site-header {
    background-color: #000;
    max-width: 1060px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 4;
}
```